# Kivy: how to handle touch events triggered from on_touch_down method of ModalView

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

Is there a way to make it so when my `ModalView`/ `Popup` widget is active but none of the buttons behind it will be triggered?

Below is an example of a ModalView/popup widget that will notify the user they entered something incorrect. I want the user to be able to click anywhere and the ModalView will disappear. The problem is that when this ModalView is visiable the buttons in the background are still active.

In this case, the BaseBoxLayout has a Label on top and Button on the bottom. I click on the button to trigger the ModalView/popup. If the user clicks on the top, the ModalView/popup disappears – as designed by my on_touch_down method.

However, if the user clicks anywhere in the bottom half (when the ModalView/popup is already triggered) then the ModalView/popup gets removed but then added again because the button in the background is still active.

How do I prevent this?

```py
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.modalview import ModalView

KV = '''
Screen:
  canvas.before:
    Color:
      rgb: [127/255,160/255,100/255]
    Rectangle:
      pos: self.pos
      size: self.size
  BaseBoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    Label:
      text: "BaseBoxLayout "
    Button:
      text: "Ok button"
      on_press: self.parent.call_popup()

<CustomPopup>
  BoxLayout:
    Label:
      text: "You can do this!"
'''

class BaseBoxLayout(BoxLayout):
  def __init__(self,**kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)

  def call_popup(self):
    print('created popup')
    self.popup = CustomPopup()
    self.popup.open()


class CustomPopup(ModalView):
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)

  def on_touch_down(self,touch):
    print('removed popup')
    self.parent.remove_widget(self)


class MainApp(MDApp):
  def build(self):
    return Builder.load_string(KV)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  MainApp().run()
```

Comment: Did you try by checking `collide_point` within method `on_touch_down` ? Or you may just return `True` from that method.

Comment: I just tried to use self.collide_point on the CustomPopup and BaseBoxLayout. It doesn’t seem to distinguish between touch_down by layer. 

What I did was replace the KV Button on_press to on_touch_down in the py - in order to print self.collide_point(touch.x,touch.y). I also printed out the same in the CustomPopup. However, when the CustomPopup is visible over the BaseBoxLayout and I press on the CustomPopup just above the Button on the BaseBoxLayout both return true. Were you thinking that only the layer I actually press would return true? Or something else that I’m not thinking of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As kivy gives you [maximum flexibility](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/inputs.html?highlight=touch%20event%20bubbling#touch-event-basics) in dispatching touch events, you can decide and implement that as you want.

Let's consider some typical situations you might come across in this scenario.

1. Your `ModalView` (I'll call it popup) needs to be dismissed as soon as you press (corresponds to `on_touch_down` event) anywhere on the screen (window). But you don't want any underlying widget to interfere at this point. Here, this means you don't want to dispatch the touch event further down the widget tree. You can do this by [returning `True`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html?highlight=touch%20event%20bubbling#widget-touch-event-bubbling) from method `on_touch_down` which will digest the event and stop it propagate further.

```py
    def on_touch_down(self,touch):
        self.parent.remove_widget(self)
        return True
```

2. You want the popup to be dismissed as before but also you don't want to override any default behavior. Call the superclass method. This is more preferable than in 1.

```py
    def on_touch_down(self,touch):
        self.parent.remove_widget(self)
        return super().on_touch_down(touch)
```

3. Perhaps your popup will not cover whole window. In that case you want it to be dismissed only if touch is within its physical boundary otherwise not. Go as in 1 or 2. But what if the touch is outside its physical boundary ? Return `True` to digest the event. If you don't handle that youself, call `super` (but remember it will dismiss the popup unless you set `auto_dismiss` to False).

```py
    def on_touch_down(self,touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            self.parent.remove_widget(self)
        # Otherwise stop propagation and digest.
        return True
        # Or for default handling.
#       return super().on_touch_down(touch)
```

There might be countable (if not infinite) no. of situations you can face here. So better stop here.